# Extracting the last section of a log file

Tags: linux, scripting, shell

How can I extract all the contents of a file which comes after a given line ? The line can be matched by exact contents or regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN { found=0; } /RE GOES HERE/ { found = 1; } found { print; }' $filename
```

Avoids multiple file traversals, so should (possibly) perform better for large files where the match is towards the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
tail -n +`egrep -n "pattern" "file_to_search.txt" | cut -d ":" -f 2 | tail -n 1` "file_to_tail.txt"
```

Comment: The section in grey (from egrep -n "pattern" to tail -n 1) is enclosed in backticks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I assume you mean cut -d ":" -f 1 to get the first field - the line number.

Comment: Second field actually. The first field would be the matching file name :)

Comment: Hm, somehow that does not work for me. Using grep 2.5.4 on OpenSUSE 11.2 . But I get the drift :-)

Answer (score 1):

This simple `awk` program should do the job:

```
awk '/pattern/,""' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

And also:

```
sed -n '/pattern/,$ p' filename
```